# How to use wordpress outside installation directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress installed to a subfolder in the root of my site. So if my site is "site.com", the wordpress is in "site.com/blog".
I want to display some posts from wordpress to pages outside of the blog directory. I have read some articles telling that to use wordpress outside it's folder i just have to include or require the "wp-load.php" from wordpress to the page. Now the problem is I have tried using this method, but when I view the page in the browser, it just redirects to "wp-admin/install.php" which doesn't exists because i am at the root directory.

Comment: Change the `site_url()` from `admin settings`

Comment: @Rohan_Kumar You mean from the wordpress dashboard? I changed it. It still redirects to wp-admin/install.php

Answer (score 0):

**Change** your `site url` from

```
http://www.site.com/blog/
```

to

```
http://www.site.com/
```

Read http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

In database it would be found in `wp_options` table

Comment: Is it okay if i just edit the table? I have changed the site address from the dashboard and is showing the correct value. but in the database, the value is the wordpress folder.